# setting utf-8 without html

Tags: php, html

I am trying to make a clear output from my table and with setting:

```
mysqli_query($con,"set names 'utf8'");
```

my output looks like this:

```
1|question|kdo je prvi slovenski predsednik?|janez janĹĄa|primoĹž trubar|dragomir veseliloviÄ|kekec|3|
```

but with HTML tags (which I do not want to use):

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>page title</title>
   <meta charset="UTF-8" />   
</head>
<body>

1|question|kdo je prvi slovenski predsednik?|janez janša|primož trubar|dragomir veselilovič|kekec|3|
```

as its supposed to.

But the question is: How can I get UTF-8 working correctly without even using HTML, only PHP?

Comment: Send a proper `Content-Type` header including the charset.

Comment: Why can't you or do not want to use it in HTML?

Comment: @CBroe How do I do that?

Comment: @Fred-ii- because then I have a whole html display in my http downloader

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=how+do+i+send+a+content-type+header+with+php

Answer (score 0):

If your code is running on a web server, you need to call [`header()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) to set the correct HTTP `Content-Type`:

```
<?php

  header ('Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8');

  echo "1|question|kdo je prvi slovenski predsednik?|janez janĹĄa|primoĹž trubar|dragomir veseliloviÄ|kekec|3|\n";
```